# PHP Foreach inside foreach display data in table row

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

How can I display data in a tablerow inside a foreach function? The agenda variable works fine, the rows variable is the one making problems, I need it inside a  tag

```
<?php
$agenda = $days = json_decode(get_field( "field_uc_content_json" ));
unset($agenda[0]); ?>



<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Day </th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
   <?php foreach($agenda as $column) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $column[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php
    $rows = explode( "\n", $column[1]);
    foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
    <tr> <?php echo $row; ?> </tr>
    <?php    } ?>
   </td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The second `foreach`

`vardump` agenda

[image]

`vardump` rows

[image]

Comment: Can you `var_dump($agenda);` and `var_dump($rows);`? I'd like to know what's inside these arrays. So I can help you displaying the values. The whole code of your `<tbody>` would also be nice.

Comment: @RonnieOosting sure, I just edited my question

Comment: Can you also edit the `<tbody>` code?

Comment: @RonnieOosting how>?

Comment: In your code i need the beginning from `<tbody>` until the `</tbody>`. Everything inside those 2 tags.

Comment: @RonnieOosting done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158870/discussion-between-ronnie-oosting-and-radu033).

Comment: You should be doing something like `foreach($agenda as $column) { ?> <tr> <php foreach($column as $row){ ?> <td> <?php echo $row[0]; ?> </td> <td> <?php echo $row[1]; ?> </td> <td> <?php echo $row[2]; ?> </td> <?php } ?> </tr> <?php } ?>`

Comment: @icecub thanks for your support in the chatroom. I've added the answer below.

Comment: @RonnieOosting Cheers m8. Hopefully OP still reads this and marks one of the answers as accepted. +1 From me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach($agenda as $column):
    $rows = explode("\n", $column[1]);?>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="<?php count($rows) + 1?>"><?php $column[0];?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;

endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

As we (and icecub) discussed in the chatroom.

Good luck friend.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is work fine now.I tested it.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background: #8da80c;">
          <th> Day </th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
   <?php foreach($agenda as $column) { ?>
   <tr style="background: #e0e545;">
    <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $column[0]; ?></td>
    <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $column[1]; ?></td>
     <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $column[2]; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tested with these values

```
  <pre>
<?php
$agenda = array (array("montag","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","08:00"),array("montag","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","08:00"),array("montag","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","08:00"));

print_r($agenda);
?>
     </pre>
```

Comment: Nah. OP isn't very clear about the actual problem. In the chat it became more clear. It's a HTML / CSS issue mostly.

Comment: Mostly. The issue is that when the data inside a column becomes to long and continues on another line, the data in the next column doesn't line up. But he's not even responding in chat anymore..

Answer (score 1):

It because you variable

```
$agenda = $days = json_decode(get_field( "field_uc_content_json" ));
unset($agenda[0]); ?>
```

it's a object and this you dont use like a array, you need manage like object in the explode, like this:

```
$rows = explode( "\n", $column->1);
```